# Spring Batch Multithreaded Job with fixed order

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-batch

I created a spring batch job that reads chunks (commit level = 10) of a flat CSV file and writes the output to another flat file. Plain and simple.
To test local scaling I also configured the tasklet with a TaskExecutor with a pool of 10 threads, thus introducing parallelism by using a multithreaded step pattern.
As expected these threads concurrently read items until their chunk is filled and the chunk is written to the output file.
Also as expected the order of the items has changed because of this concurrent reading.
But is it possible to maintain the fixed order, preferably still leveraging the increased performance gained by using multiple threads?

Comment: Hi, I have same problem. I used FlatFileItemReader and FlatFileItemWriter for reader and writer respectively. But both are not thread-safe. I have tried to use TaskExecutor, but the reasults are not proper. The order of rows as well as columns is not proper. Can you please post your solution. I mean which reader/writer you have used and the hack you used for proper ordering of write operation.

Comment: hi @nkr1pt can you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of an easy way. A workaround would be to prefix all lines with an ID which is created sequentially while reading. After finishing the job, sort the lines by the id. Sounds hacky, but should work.

Comment: I can't see how I can prefix items with an ID to maintain order during concurrent reading. Prefixing the items with an ID implies sequential reading imo?

Comment: Well obviously the reader threads would have to use the same shared counter instance. Something like [`AtomicLong.incrementAndGet()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html#incrementAndGet%28%29) where all threads share an AtomicLong instance.

Comment: Is this still the only way we can achieve this? Any examples?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any easy solution, but only using one writer thread (that also performs a sort when writing) and multiple reading threads could work but it would not be as scalable..

Comment: This implies that the items first should be ordered by for example prefixing them with an ID as suggested by Sean Patrick Floyd, so that we can later sort them in memory before writing. But because the items are read concurrently, we can't provide an order while reading, this should be done in a sequential process?